# PostgreSQL querying for array containing ids from a separate table

Tags: postgresql

I have a `users` table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  email text,
  account_id integer,
  segment_ids integer[]
);
```

And a `segments` table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE segments (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name text
);
```

I have built a query like this to find all the users which belong to segments:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
  WHERE segment_ids @> (
    SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT id from segments 
        WHERE name IN ('Melbourne', 'Male', 'Team #1')
    )
  )
```

However, I am not satisfied that using a subquery is the best way to accomplish this. Is there a cleaner way of writing this query, i.e. with a joins, or is a subquery the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) function to do this:

For example, with the above tables and this data:

```
insert into segments values (1, 'one');
insert into segments values (2, 'two');
insert into segments values (3, 'three');

insert into users values (1, 'email@example.com', 1, array[1,2]);
insert into users values (2, 'email2@example.com', 2, array[2,3]);
```

Running the following query:

```
select u.id, u.email, u.account_id, u.segment_id, s.name from 
(select u.id, u.email, u.account_id, unnest(u.segment_ids) segment_id from users u) as u 
right join segments s on s.id = u.segment_id
```

yields:

```
1   "email@example.com"     1   1   "one"
1   "email@example.com"     1   2   "two"
2   "email2@example.com"    2   2   "two"
2   "email2@example.com"    2   3   "three"
```

Comment: Could I then add a `WHERE` on the end to match segment names, only returning the users that have the combination of segments specified?

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to you could perform a join.

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a4d2a/3)

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.* 
FROM users 
JOIN segments 
  ON ( segments.id = ANY( users.segment_ids ) )
ORDER BY 1;
```

And if you really need to see what the segment_id that it matched:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.*, array_agg(segments.id) "matched segment id"
FROM users 
JOIN segments 
  ON ( segments.id = ANY( users.segment_ids ) )
GROUP BY users.id, email, account_id, segment_ids
ORDER BY 1;
```

***Insert your `WHERE segments.name IN(...)` wherever you see fit***

---

Credit: @JamesFry for the DDL statements in the fiddle

Comment: Thank you @vol7tron but I think this doesn't use a `WHERE` like I specified in my original question. How would I use a `WHERE` in your query?